# When Activity is destroyed, all services execute onStart() methods, including activity that is destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, oncreate

I'm expirencing strange behavior. It all worked like charm until the other day. Now it's working all wrong. 
How is possible that when i swipe away Main Activity from the screen, all of my running services are executing onStartCommand() methods ? MainActivity is also executing onCreate() method. Even AutoStartService is executing onStartCommand(), and that service has no function after boot-completed.
How is this possible ?
Is my Android Studio coruped ? 
What can cause this behaviour ?

I registerd geofence in Main Activity, and now it's firing all the time, when i open the app, when i close the app.

I have notification that leads to the main activity.When i'm on the main screen of the app, and i swipe notifications down and i tap on it, MainActivity is again executing onCreate() method instead just loading it, cause it's not destroyed.
It all worked fine, i have tested it before.

What can i do?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I managed to solve it by changing the return of `onStartCommand()` method to:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){ ...
   ....
   return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I recommend seeing this article [Android Services Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)